# Translating a genome sequence into possible frames

Tags: sequence-alignment, ngs, proteins, blast, phylogenetics

I have a sequence below from MYC gene about which I need to translate the sequence in all possible frames AND identify (for each frame) which codons are actually used in MYC

```
AAAGCAATAATACAATTTAAAACCTGGGTCTCTAGAGGTGTTAGGACGTG
GTGTTGGGTAGGCGCAGGCAGGGGAAAAGGGAGGCGAGGATGTGTCCGAT
TCTCCTGGAATCGTTGACTTGGAAAAACCAGGGCGAATCTCCGCACCCAG
CCCTGACTCCCCTGCCGCGGCCGCCCTCGGGTGTCCTCGCGCCCGAGATG
CGGAGGAACTGCGAGGAGCGGGGCTCTGGGCGGTTCCAGAACAGCTGCTA
CCCTTGGTGGGGTGGCTCCGGGGGAGGTATCGCAGCGGGGTCTCTGGCGC
AGTTGCATCTCCGTATTGAGTGCGAAGGGAGGTGCCCCTATTATTATTTG
ACACCCCCCTTGTATTTATGGAGGGGTGTTAAAGCCCGCGGCTGAGCTCG
CCACTCCAGCCGGCGAGAGAAAGAAGAAAAGCTGGCAAAAGGAGTGTTGG
ACGGGGGCGGTACTGGGGGTGGGGACGGGGGCGGTGGAGAGGGAAGGTTG
GGAGGGGCTGCGGTGCCGGCGGGGGTAGGAGAGCGGCTAGGGCGCGAGTG
GGAACAGCCGCAGCGGAGGGGCCCCGGCGCGGAGCGGGGTTCACGCAGCC
GCTAGCGCCCAGGCGCCTCTCGCCTTCTCCTTCAGGTGGCGCAAAACTTT
GTGCCTTGGATTTTGGCAAATTGTTTTCCTCACCGCCACCTCCCGCGGCT
TCTTAAGGGCGCCAGGGCCGATTTCGATTCCTCTGCCGCTGCGGGGCCGA
CTCCCGGGCTTTGCGCTCCGGGCTCCCGGGGGAGCGGGGGCTCGGCGGGC
ACCAAGCCGCTGGTTCACTAAGTGCGTCTCCGAGATAGCAGGGGACTGTC
CAAAGGGGGTGAAAGGGTGCTCCCTTTATTCCCCCACCAAGACCACCCAG
CCGCTTTAGGGGATAGCTCTGCAAGGGGAGAGGTTCGGGACTGTGGCGCG
CACTGCGCGCTGCGCCAGGTTTCCGCACCAAGACCCCTTTAACTCAAGAC
TGCCTCCCGCTTTGTGTGCCCCGCTCCAGCAGCCTCCCGCGACGATGCCC
CTCAACGTTAGCTTCACCAACAGGAACTATGACCTCGACTACGACTCGGT
GCAGCCGTATTTCTACTGCGACGAGGAGGAGAACTTCTACCAGCAGCAGC
AGCAGAGCGAGCTGCAGCCCCCGGCGCCCAGCGAGGATATCTGGAAGAAA
TTCGAGCTGCTGCCCACCCCGCCCCTGTCCCCTAGCCGCCGCTCCGGGCT
CTGCTCGCCCTCCTACGTTGCGGTCACACCCTTCTCCCTTCGGGGAGACA
```

Where should I look for all 4 pieces of information easily? Please guide.

Comment: How do you know it's MYC gene? The answer is quite dependent on it, but in general, you probably want to just align the seuqence to a genome annotation.

Answer (score 1):

The 6-frame translation  results are below you will need to do the rest. It is translated 5' to 3' but appears to contain two splice sites. You will need to use blast to resolve the start/stop of the splicing.

All 6-codon translation is available the Expasy server [here](https://web.expasy.org/translate/). You will need to blast to resolve the splicing.

---

5'3' Frame 1
KAIIQFKTWVSRGVRTWCWVGAGRGKGRRGCVRFSWNR-LGKTRANLRTQP-LPCRGRPRVSSRPRCGGTARSGALGGSRTAATLGGVAPGEVSQRGLWRSCISVLSAKGGAPIII-HPPCIYGGVLKPAAELATPAGERKKKSWQKECWTGAVLGVGTGAVEREGWEGLRCRRG-ESG-GASGNSRSGGAPARSGVHAAASAQAPLAFSFRWRKTLCLGFWQIVFLTATSRGFLRAPGPISIPLPLRGRLPGFALRAPGGAGARRAPSRWFTKCVSEIAGDCPKGVKGCSLYSPTKTTQPL-GIALQGERFGTVARTARCARFPHQDPFNSRLPPALCAPLQQPPATMPLNVSFTNRNYDLDYDSVQPYFYCDEEENFYQQQQQSELQPPAPSEDIWKKFELLPTPPLSPSRRSGLCSPSYVAVTPFSLRGD
5'3' Frame 2
KQ-YNLKPGSLEVLGRGVG-AQAGEKGGEDVSDSPGIVDLEKPGRISAPSPDSPAAAALGCPRARDAEELRGAGLWAVPEQLLPLVGWLRGRYRSGVSGAVASPY-VRREVPLLLFDTPLVFMEGC-SPRLSSPLQPARERRKAGKRSVGRGRYWGWGRGRWRGKVGRGCGAGGGRRAARARVGTAAAEGPRRGAGFTQPLAPRRLSPSPSGGAKLCALDFGKLFSSPPPPAAS-GRQGRFRFLCRCGADSRALRSGLPGERGLGGHQAAGSLSASPR-QGTVQRG-KGAPFIPPPRPPSRFRG-LCKGRGSGLWRALRAAPGFRTKTPLTQDCLPLCVPRSSSLPRRCPSTLASPTGTMTSTTTRCSRISTATRRRTSTSSSSRASCSPRRPARISGRNSSCCPPRPCPLAAAPGSARPPTLRSHPSPFGET
5'3' Frame 3
SNNTI-NLGL-RC-DVVLGRRRQGKREARMCPILLESLTWKNQGESPHPALTPLPRPPSGVLAPEMRRNCEERGSGRFQNSCYPWWGGSGGGIAAGSLAQLHLRIECEGRCPYYYLTPPLYLWRGVKARG-ARHSSRREKEEKLAKGVLDGGGTGGGDGGGGEGRLGGAAVPAGVGERLGREWEQPQRRGPGAERGSRSR-RPGASRLLLQVAQNFVPWILANCFPHRHLPRLLKGARADFDSSAAAGPTPGLCAPGSRGSGGSAGTKPLVH-VRLRDSRGLSKGGERVLPLFPHQDHPAALGDSSARGEVRDCGAHCALRQVSAPRPL-LKTASRFVCPAPAASRDDAPQR-LHQQEL-PRLRLGAAVFLLRRGGELLPAAAAERAAAPGAQRGYLEEIRAAAHPAPVP-PPLRALLALLRCGHTLLPSGR
3'5' Frame 1
CLPEGRRV-PQRRRASRARSGG-GTGAGWAAARISSRYPRWAPGAAARSAAAAGRSSPPRRSRNTAAPSRSRGHSSCW-S-R-GASSREAAGAGHTKREAVLS-RGLGAETWRSAQCAPQSRTSPLAELSPKAAGWSWWGNKGSTLSPPLDSPLLSRRRT--TSGLVPAEPPLPREPGAQSPGVGPAAAEESKSALAPLRSRGRWR-GKQFAKIQGTKFCAT-RRRREAPGR-RLREPRSAPGPLRCGCSHSRPSRSPTPAGTAAPPNLPSPPPPSPPPVPPPSNTPFASFSSFSRRLEWRAQPRALTPLHKYKGGVK---GHLPSHSIRRCNCARDPAAIPPPEPPHQG-QLFWNRPEPRSSQFLRISGARTPEGGRGRGVRAGCGDSPWFFQVNDSRRIGHILASLFPCLRLPNTTS-HL-RPRF-IVLLL
3'5' Frame 2
VSPKGEGCDRNVGGRAEPGAAARGQGRGGQQLEFLPDILAGRRGLQLALLLLLVEVLLLVAVEIRLHRVVVEVIVPVGEANVEGHRRGRLLERGTQSGRQS-VKGVLVRKPGAARSARHSPEPLPLQSYPLKRLGGLGGGIKGAPFHPLWTVPCYLGDALSEPAAWCPPSPRSPGSPERKARESAPQRQRNRNRPWRP-EAAGGGGEENNLPKSKAQSFAPPEGEGERRLGASGCVNPAPRRGPSAAAVPTRALAALLPPPAPQPLPTFPLHRPRPHPQYRPRPTLLLPAFLLSLAGWSGELSRGL-HPSINTRGVSNNNRGTSLRTQYGDATAPETPLRYLPRSHPTKGSSCSGTAQSPAPRSSSASRARGHPRAAAAGESGLGAEIRPGFSKSTIPGESDTSSPPFSPACAYPTPRPNTSRDPGFKLYYCF
3'5' Frame 3
SPRREKGVTAT-EGEQSPERRLGDRGGVGSSSNFFQISSLGAGGCSSLCCCCW-KFSSSSQ-KYGCTES-SRS-FLLVKLTLRGIVAGGCWSGAHKAGGSLELKGSWCGNLAQRAVRATVPNLSPCRAIP-SGWVVLVGE-REHPFTPFGQSPAISETHLVNQRLGARRAPAPPGARSAKPGSRPRSGRGIEIGPGALKKPREVAVRKTICQNPRHKVLRHLKEKARGAWALAAA-TPLRAGAPPLRLFPLAP-PLSYPRRHRSPSQPSLSTAPVPTPSTAPVQHSFCQLFFFLSPAGVASSAAGFNTPP-IQGGCQIIIGAPPFALNTEMQLRQRPRCDTSPGATPPRVAAVLEPPRAPLLAVPPHLGREDTRGRPRQGSQGWVRRFALVFPSQRFQENRTHPRLPFPLPAPTQHHVLTPLETQVLNCIIA

Comment: thank you so much for your help. May I please ask for some more information to do this independently and confidently in future? 1. I want to stick to NCBI's tools. Is NCBI ORF finder a good tool for 6-frame translation and which parameters should I use? 2. To detect the paralogs, can you please explain the reasons behind "10,000" results and "60-80%" divergence. Also, which blast tool (blastx, tblastn etc.) should I use? 3. Can I find network of interacting proteins on KEGG ?

Comment: I've re-edited your question and my answer to ensure compliance with site rules. Long multipart questions fall into the category of "vagueness". Please read how the site works at bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/tour and 
 https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask  Ultimately it is orientated towards a third user identifying the answer from a off-site search engine, thus the title needs to be specific to the question